# Qt Virtual Keyboard in QQuickWidget

Tags: qt, qt5, virtual-keyboard, qquickwidget

It is possible to show Virtual Keyboard in QQuickWidget or in QWidget?

I have QWidget application and I need to have better control where VirtualKeyboard is shown.

Today I spend all my day to find a solution, unfortunately without success.

Comment: some feedback??'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code shows that it is valid to use virtualkeyboard in QQuickWidget.

**main.cpp**

```cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQuickWidget>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    qputenv("QT_IM_MODULE", QByteArray("qtvirtualkeyboard"));
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQuickWidget widget;
    widget.setResizeMode(QQuickWidget::SizeRootObjectToView);
    widget.setSource(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    widget.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.14
import QtQuick.Window 2.14
import QtQuick.VirtualKeyboard 2.14

Rectangle {
    id: window
    width: 640
    height: 480

    TextEdit{
        text: "Hello world"
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }

    InputPanel {
        id: inputPanel
        z: 99
        x: 0
        y: window.height
        width: window.width

        states: State {
            name: "visible"
            when: inputPanel.active
            PropertyChanges {
                target: inputPanel
                y: window.height - inputPanel.height
            }
        }
        transitions: Transition {
            from: ""
            to: "visible"
            reversible: true
            ParallelAnimation {
                NumberAnimation {
                    properties: "y"
                    duration: 250
                    easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**qml.qrc**

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>main.qml</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

**59777221.pro**

```
QT += quickwidgets virtualkeyboard
CONFIG += c++11
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS
SOURCES +=  main.cpp
RESOURCES += qml.qrc
```

```
├── 59777221.pro
├── main.cpp
├── main.qml
└── qml.qrc
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try it in Python ? and example please?

Comment: @Gaston see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62473386/pyqt5-show-virtual-keyboard/62522005#62522005